# Como colocar um timeout ou desabilitar um botão por tempo definido em PHP ou Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Galera, primeiramente desculpem o contexto da pergunta parece muito repetitiva mas não é.

Bom queria saber se é possível colocar um *timeout* em um botão da minha página na Web **independente** da pessoa que acesse. Ao clicar, outra pessoa só poderá clicar novamente após 1 hora. É viável fazer isso sem a necessidade de um BD?

Andei pesquisando mas não consegui resolver, por isso resolvi perguntar.

Comment: Você está falando de duas pessoas em computadores diferentes, interferindo uma no botão da outra sem a necessidade de BD?

Comment: Sim, por exemplo o botão 1 está ativo, e alguém clicou, logo outros só poderão clicar após uma hora. Nessas condições o botão seria desabilitado no meu servidor(no código). Assim não havendo necessidades de um BD, é possível?

Comment: Sem conexão com banco de dados, não creio que seja possível.

Comment: bom você pode gerar um arquivo txt ai verificar o tempo apertir dai

Comment: Certo Marcos, é realmente uma ótima ideia, mas como exatamente  eu faria isso?

Comment: Você pode utilizar uma estrutura real time, desta forma em cada acesso de um usuário novo, cria-se uma sessão no servidor. Recomendo a utilização do [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org) com [Socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Comment: adicionei uma  resposta, mais ou  menos a logica é essa, mas  n tive como testar aqui

Comment: Adicionei a minha resposta opção com Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sem biblioteca**

OBS: Para você não ficar esperando 1 hora, no teste no exemplo acima coloquei 2 minutos apesar de aparecer no botão quando desabilitado o tempo em relação a 1 hora.

```
//pega dados do arquivo
$result=file_get_contents("timerdobotao.txt");

//Unix timestamp data atual
$timestamp = time();

//diferença entra as datas
$unixDif = $timestamp-$result;

//minutos que faltam para ativar o botão
$minFaltam =(int)(60-($unixDif/60));

if(isset($_POST['click']))
{
    //salva timastamp da data atual no arquivo
    file_put_contents("timerdobotao.txt", $timestamp);
}

if ($minFaltam<0){
    //salva timastamp da data atual no arquivo
    file_put_contents("timerdobotao.txt", $timestamp);

    echo "<form action='' method='post'>
      <button type='submit' name='click' class='click'>Entrar</button>
    </form>";

}else{

  echo "<button type='button' class='entrar' disabled>Acesso para 1º usuario a clicar aqui em ".$minFaltam." min</button>";
}
```

**Com Jquery**

> para teste 3 minutos de acesso para o primeiro usuário a clicar no botão `Entrar`

- Se o acesso estiver liberado, a primeira pessoa que clicar no botão `Entrar` terá acesso a página por `60 minutos` ou o indicado na variável `$tempoConcedido` no inicio do código.
- Outros usuários verão em uma mensagem com contagem regressiva o tempo que falta para poder acessar a página, e ao final da contagem essa mensagem se transforma em botão `Entrar` para poder tentar acessar já que primeiro a clicar entra e bloqueia o acesso dos demais.

  ```
  <?php

  $timestamp="";
  $timestamp="";

  //tempo em minutos para habilitar novo acesso
  $tempoConcedido=3;

  //arquivo que irá conter o timestamp para uso nos calculos do script
  $filename = "timestamp.txt";

  //Unix timestamp data atual
  $timestamp = time();

  //se o arquivo existir calcula quantos minutos faltam para liberar novo acesso
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
      //pega dados do arquivo
      $result=file_get_contents($filename);

      //diferença entra os timestamps
      $unixDif = $timestamp-$result;

      $unixDifMinutos = ($unixDif/60);

      //minutos que faltam para ativar o botão
      $minFaltam = (int)($tempoConcedido-$unixDifMinutos);    

  }else{

      $minFaltam=0;

  }

  //se o cookie não existir executa o codigo abaixo
  if (!isset($_COOKIE["acessoLivre"])){

      if ($minFaltam<=0){

          if(isset($_POST['click'])){
              //salva timastamp da data atual no arquivo
              file_put_contents($filename, $timestamp);
              setcookie('acessoLivre', 'umaHora', (time() + (1 * 120)));
              header('Location: contdown-desabilita-botao.php');
              exit();
          }

          echo "<form action='' method='post'>
            <button type='submit' name='click' class='click'>Entrar</button>
          </form>";

      }else{

          echo "<div id='desabilitado'><form action='' method='post'><button type='button' class='entrar' disabled>Acesso para 1º usuario a clicar aqui em <span id='time'></span></button></form></div>";    
      }
  }

  //mostra o tempo que falta para outro usuario poder acessar a página
  if ($minFaltam>0){

  ?>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

      function startTimer(duration, display) {
          var timer = duration,
              minutes, seconds;

          interval = setInterval(function() {
              minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
              seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

              minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
              seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

              display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

              if (--timer < 0) {
                  //muda a div que contem o botão com contador regressivo para o botão de acesso
                  $('#desabilitado').html('<form action="" method="post"><button type="submit" name="click" class="click">Entrar</button></form>');
                  $("#registration-form").submit()
                  clearInterval(interval);
              }
          }, 1000);

          return new Date();
      }

      jQuery(function($) {
          s = <?php echo $minFaltam ?>;
          var Minutes = 60 * s,
              display = $('#time');

          var startDate = startTimer(Minutes, display);  

      });

      </script>

  <?php
  }
  ?>

  <?php
  if (isset($_COOKIE["acessoLivre"])){
      echo "<h1>Pagina liberada</h1>";

      echo ($_COOKIE["acessoLivre"]);
  }
  ?>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Arquivo **clickado.php**

```
<?php
    $time = time();
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $fp = fopen("timerdobotao.txt", "w+");
    $escreve = fwrite($fp, $time);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Arquivo  **verificabotao.php**

```
<?php
   $arquivo = fopen ('timerdobotao.txt', 'r');
   $rt = "false";
   while(!feof($arquivo)){
     $linha = fgets($arquivo, 1024);
     if($linha !=""){
        if($linha < (time() - (1 * 60 * 60))){ // horas * minutos * segundos
           $rt = "true";
        }
     }
   }
echo $rt;
?>
```

No seu html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
   function ClickDoBotao(){
       var usuario = "idDoUsuario";
       $.post("clickado.php",{usuario:usuario}function(){

       })
   }
   setInterval(function(){
      var usuario = "idDoUsuario";
      setInterval(function(){
         $.get("verificabotao.php",{usuario:usuario},function(rt){
            if(rt == "true"){
                $("#meuBotao").prop("disabled",false);
            }else{
                $("#meuBotao").prop("disabled",true);
            }
         });
      }, 5000);
   });
</script>
```

Cire um botão e atribua um id

```
<button onclick="ClickDoBotao()" id="meuBotao">
```

Obs não tive como testar o  codigo mas a logica é essa

Comment: Não funcionou aqui comigo.

Comment: É aqui também não funcionou, mas tô tentando resolver, a lógica foi boa, acho que tá com erro a capturar o tempo do txt.